# sampsize error in Random Forests

Tags: r

I want to set different sampsize for randomForest in R. I expect to see 3 different RF return, but the error occured in R  "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'"

and my code is as follows

```
    sampsize_vect<-vector("list",3)
    sampsize_vect[[1]]<- rep(6670,3)
    sampsize_vect[[2]]<- c(1000)
    sampsize_vect[[3]]<- c(5000,5000)
    for (i in 1:3) {
    RF <- randomForest (x,y,sampsize=sampsize_vect[i],node.size=3,do.trace=FALSE,importance=TRUE,ntree=150,,forest=TRUE)
    print(RF)
    }
```

Why this happened and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with the random forests. You simply used `[` when you should have used `[[` (or vice versa, I suppose).

Change `sampsize = sampsize_vect[i]` to `sampsize = sampsize_vect[[i]]]`. Always remember, with lists `[[` selects an *element* while `[` selects a *sub-list*.

Comment: @floodking My original answer still applies. Additionally, passing a vector to `sampsize` only has an effect if you are doing stratified resampling, which your example is not. Finally, it is `nodesize` not `node.size`.

Comment: Thanks for help. I think I did not describe the problem properly, I want to run RF with three differen sampsize vector but these three vector might not be the same length, so I used "sampsize = sampsize_vect[i]" to obtain the three vectors(sub-list) but failed.

Comment: @floodking That's nonsensical, unless you also change the strata argument. Did you read my comment regarding the fact that sampsize of length greater than one only applies when doing stratified sampling?

Comment: @floodking And in any case, my original comment regarding `[[` _still_ applies!

Comment: @jordan, I want to make a comparison.All the three size vectors i.e. sampsize= c(1000),sampsize= c(5000,5000),or sampsize= rep(6670,3), can run alone in RF. I want to combine all the cases with a loop. What shall I do?

Comment: @jordan. Thanks. I got it. Thanks again for your hel and patience.